# Generalizing the notion of "radix" to rational, irrational, or even imaginary numbers

Tags: number-theory

I know to covert any natural number to any natural Base. For eg., $$10=1\cdot2^3+0\cdot2^2+1\cdot2^1+0\cdot2^0$$
Hence *ten* in binary is $1010$.

> But what if I want to expand this *limit* of the radix from natural numbers to, say, rational numbers or, say, to irrational numbers(!), or maybe, even to imaginary numbers?

Does this notion of "Radix" even make any sense? Or will this open a new "field" of mathematics?

What will be the pros and cons of *generalizing* the base of numbers like this? Is this be practical?

Comment: You can also write rational numbers in binary for example, $\frac 34 = \frac 12 + \frac 1{2^2} $ so in binary it is $0.11$

Comment: I'm honestly a bit careful about this question, you see, all my previous questions have negative votes, and I don't want the same with this one too,. So can you please point out if there is any mistake in mistake in this question which I can work upon? Your suggestions are welcome : )

Comment: @StackpackedKar what about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number ?? Does this look like something you need?

Comment: thanks everybody.

Comment: how much time should I wait before accepting an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are positional notations with bases that are not positive integers:

- In systems with [negative bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base), both positive and negative numbers can be expressed with a single sequence of digits without any prepended sign for negative numbers.
- Systems with [complex bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex-base_system) extends this to being able to can express arbitrary *complex numbers* with a single sequence of digits.

These systems work well enough *mathematically* -- the reason they're mostly considered just intellectual curiosities is that it can be difficult for human readers to grasp numbers at a glance. They could be used for arithmetic *internally* in computers, but they still make life complex for the programmer, and in the majority of cases this outweighs the few theoretical nice points they have.

Systems with *fractional or irrational bases* can be imagined, but there we quickly begin to lose nice properties. The *number of different digits* we work with is by necessity always a natural number -- and since it cannot match an irrational base we either end up in a situation where there are significant gaps in the number line that we cannot represent (because there are too few digits), or we end up with numbers that have *many different* representations.

The problem of representations not being unique also arises (in a more tame form) with integral bases too -- in base ten we need to accept that $0.9999\ldots$ and $1.000\ldots$ represent the same real number, which occasionally confuses students a lot. But at least in an integral base, each number as *at most two* representations. In an non-integral basis, a number might have *infinitely many different representations*, and it would be very difficult to determine if two representations denote the same number -- or if they don't, then which of them is larger.